# Color text in a file using grep

Tags: string, grep

I have  a 'data.txt' file with a long continuous string. I need to color the part of the string that comes between two particular sub strings. How do I that using grep?

I am using  OpenSuse12.3.

Comment: Do you mean you need to `grep --color=always <your_search> <<< <your_string>` some substring in your string?

Comment: No. I need something like this
grep --color=always [color entire string from 'sub_string_1' to 'sub_string_2'] data.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the screenshot, if it is what you are looking for. In this case, the two words are `foo` and `bar`

If yes, you could try the grep regex in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!. It worked.A question though, what do I need to change in the code if I want to color `foo` and `bar` as well?

Comment: @fts then you don't need look around at all. just `grep -color... -P 'foo.*?bar'`